# How to extract the text infront of the sample using python3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text-processing

Here is the sample record that I am having.

```
Record ID:           9211
User name:           Administrator first
User principal name: Administrator@example.com
When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52
When changed:         2000-06-10 4:8:55
Account expires:      Never
```

I would like to extract the data from infront of the values. The output must come like the following:

```
9211
Administrator first
Administrator
first
Administrator@example.com
1999-12-23 3:8:52
2000-06-10 4:8:55
Never
```

The word `Administrator first` must be extracted and separated as shown above.
I tried the following inorder to extract the `User name` from the sample but did not get any output.

```
re.findall(r'User name:           (\w+)', i)
```

Kindly,let me know how I can achieve this? There should be only extracted data and not space which is given before data.

Kindly, let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why not split on ``:`` and then ``strip()``? If split yields more than 2 items, you throw away the first and join the others back together. If it's exactly 2 items you only want the second (and then strip it).

Comment: @mpf82 no need for join `line.split(':',1)[1].strip()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands but what about the lines with a time (or other lines with multiple ``:``)? e.g. ``2000-06-10 4:8:55``

Comment: @mpf82 it works, i'm using the 2nd arg of `str.split()` try `'When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52'.split(':',1)[1].strip()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands right, sorry, I didn't notice you've set the ``maxsplit`` parameter on ``split()`` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may use a dict comprehension

```
import re

string = """
Record ID:           9211
User name:           Administrator first
User principal name: Administrator@example.com
When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52
When changed:         2000-06-10 4:8:55
Account expires:      Never
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>[^:\n]+):\s*(?P<value>.+)', re.MULTILINE)
result = {m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(string)}
print(result)
```

Afterwards, just ask your dict for ie `result['User name']`. See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/CuiN6i).

---

If you have ***multiple occurences*** of the entries and the entries have always the same format (ie they start with `Record ID` and end with `Account expires`), you could wrap another expression and a class around it so that you end up with a *list of dictionaries:*

```
import re
string = """
Record ID:           9211
User name:           Administrator first
User principal name: Administrator@example.com
When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52
When changed:         2000-06-10 4:8:55
Account expires:      Never

Record ID:           9390
User name:           Administrator first
User principal name: Administrator@example.com
When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52
When changed:         2000-06-10 4:8:55
Account expires:      Never
"""

class Analyzer:
    ''' Parses the input string and returns matched entries '''
    rx_parts = re.compile(r'^Record ID:(?s:.+?)^Account expires:.+', re.MULTILINE)
    rx_entries = re.compile(r'^(?P<key>[^:\n]+):\s*(?P<value>.+)', re.MULTILINE)
    result = list()

    def __init__(self, input_string = None):
        self.result = [{m.group('key'): m.group('value') 
                        for m in self.rx_entries.finditer(part.group(0))}
                        for part in self.rx_parts.finditer(input_string)]

    def query(self, key=None, value=None):
        try:
            subset = [item for item in self.result if item[key] == value]
        except KeyError:
            subset = []
        return subset

a = Analyzer(string)
admin = a.query(key = 'Record ID', value='9390')
print(admin)
```

Comment: What if I have a file of such records. I tried to pass it line by line but could not get anything. Can you help me, if you can add something to the answer?

Comment: @JafferWilson: Do you have all items every time?

Comment: Most of the time.

Comment: @JafferWilson: Updated, introduced a class.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a naive approach:

```
text = """Record ID:           9211
User name:           Administrator first
User principal name: Administrator@example.com
When created:         1999-12-23 3:8:52
When changed:         2000-06-10 4:8:55
Account expires:      Never"""

# cut text at newline chars
for line in text.splitlines():
    # find the first ':'
    idx=line.index(':')
    # remove spaces from the start
    strippedLine = line[idx+1:].lstrip()
    if 'User name' in line:
        print (strippedLine)
```

Comment: What If I want only the user name?

Comment: i modified my answer to answer that

Answer (score 1):

Using `r'User name:\s*(\w+\s*\w*)'` as the regex string seems to work; it looks as though the issue was the whitespace between the field name and the value that was causing and issue, as well as the whitespace between the first and last words in the value (for the values that have them, hence the `*` matching).

Comment: Can you please add a single line that will show the use of `re.search` or `re.findall` using your regex and storing output in a variable? If possible please let me know. Thank you

Comment: In python shell, after importing re and putting the sample provided into `sample_string`:
`>>>username_regex=re.compile(r'User name:\s*(\w+\s*\w*)')

>>>found_username=username_regex.findall(sample_string)

>>>found_username

['Administrator first']`

So you could simply grab it from `found_username[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is turn each line into a list and use the `.split()` method on the list to split the string into two separate list indexes. Eg.
If I split the phrase "Good People" and split it by the " " (space), then I'd get a list with two indexes, "People" at the 0th index and "People" at the first.

I've probably explained this terribly so you can go check out other posts on the split method.

Comment: You do not "use the split method on the list". You use the split method on the string to get a list.